# Automatically map an Excel XmlMap to a worksheet in VBA without knowing the schema XPaths

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xpath

I am building an Excel file that downloads from an API.

It can automatically generate the XmlMap from the URL schema metadata. However I then need to map the XmlMap elements to ListObjects in order to pull the data and put on a worksheet.

The code to do this is `range.Xpath.SetValue map xPath` for each item (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xpath-setvalue-method-excel)):

```vb
Sub CreateXMLList() 
    Dim mapContact As XmlMap 
    Dim strXPath As String 
    Dim lstContacts As ListObject 
    Dim objNewCol As ListColumn 

    ' Specify the schema map to use. 
    Set mapContact = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("Contacts") 

    ' Create a new list. 
    Set lstContacts = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add 

    ' Specify the first element to map. 
    strXPath = "/Root/Person/FirstName" 
    ' Map the element. 
    lstContacts.ListColumns(1).XPath.SetValue mapContact, strXPath 

    ' Specify the second element to map. 
    strXPath = "/Root/Person/LastName" 
    ' Add a column to the list. 
    Set objNewCol = lstContacts.ListColumns.Add 
    ' Map the element. 
    objNewCol.XPath.SetValue mapContact, strXPath 

    strXPath = "/Root/Person/Address/Zip" 
    Set objNewCol = lstContacts.ListColumns.Add 
    objNewCol.XPath.SetValue mapContact, strXPath 
End Sub
```

Here's the schema output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <xsd:element name="root" nillable="true" >
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" name="list-item" form="unqualified">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">

                            <xsd:element name="data_source_organization"
                                minOccurs="0"
                                nillable="true"
                                type="xsd:string"
                                form="unqualified"
                            />

                            <xsd:element name="survey_name"
                                minOccurs="0"
                                nillable="true"
                                type="xsd:string"
                                form="unqualified"
                            />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Here's the data (from which Excel automatically gets the schema and creates the XmlMap, if using the GUI):

```xml
<root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/api/domain/schema/?format=xml">
    <list-item>
        <data_source_organization>An org</data_source_organization>
        <survey_name>A Survey</survey_name>
    </list-item>
    <list-item>
        <data_source_organization>An org</data_source_organization>
        <survey_name>Another Survey</survey_name>
    </list-item>
</root>
```

However I don't want to specify the XPath strings - I want Excel to get everything from the schema metadata, just like it does if you use the GUI functionality (Data, Get External Data, From Other Sources, XML, paste a URL) - this automatically creates an XML map, creates a ListObject on the worksheet, maps every column in the source data, and grabs and displays the data. (If you record a macro doing this, it skips the mapping step.)

- Can I point an XmlMap to a cell, range or ListObject?
- Can I iterate the XmlMap and retrieve every list-item XPath?
- Some other way?

To experiment/reproduce, save the above XML as files, then create a sub as follows:

```vb
Set currentMap = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add("C:\path\to\schema.xml", "root")
currentMap.DataBinding.LoadSettings "path\to\data.xml"
' Do something to map the XmlMap elements to cells in the spreadsheet
' eg, objNewCol.XPath.SetValue currentMap, "root/data_source_organization"
' But some method that does not involve naming the Xml paths but iterates the schema
currentMap.DataBinding.Refresh
```

If the XmlMap is mapped to cells, those cells will populate with data.

Comment: Please show XML content. You would need to build an [XSD](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/) schema file to auto map.

Comment: The schema is required to generate the XmlMap, but I'm already managing that - it is mapping the XmlMap to cells that is illuding me!

Comment: Almost there...Now please add the XML content for a full reproducible example.

Comment: I've added steps so you can play yourself, thanks (the schema is pages long but the rest is much the same). The solution needs to be independent of the schema, as the schema changes and the mapping needs to reflect that, but this allows you to grapple with the problem.

Comment: I need the actually XML data source not just schema. What are you trying to map to spreadsheet?

Comment: Of course, sorry I misunderstood you, added above.

Comment: I've just discovered `ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport`, which seems to call `/schema/` on my version of Excel but not a colleague's. Just waiting for a colleague to retest - if not `XmlImport` has an `XmlMap` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [Workbooks.OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-openxml-method-excel) method as your XML file is flat and simple with one-child level for easy tabular import:

```vb
Sub ImportXML()   
     Workbooks.OpenXML "C:\Path\To\File.xml", , xlXmlLoadImportToList
End Sub
```

[image: Raw XML Import]

---

Now, if your XML is complex with nested child elements, consider building and running [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. Such transformations can be automated with the [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742(v=vs.85).aspx) library, available as a VBA reference. Note: XSLT is not an XSD schema file but part of the extensible stylesheet family of which includes XPath.

Below XSLT removes the namespace from original XML. But script can be used to flatten nested, complex structures to flat, simple ones like your posted example.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file; removes any namespace and attributes from document)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**VBA**

```vb
Sub XSLTransformAndImport()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    ' SELECT Microsoft XML, v6 AS VBA REFERENCE
    Dim xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xslDoc.async = False
    xmldoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Input.xml"
    xslDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLTScript.xsl"

    ' TRANSFORM XML
    xmldoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    ' IMPORT INTO WORKBOOK AS TABLE
    Workbooks.OpenXML "C:\Path\To\Output.xml", , xlXmlLoadImportToList

ExitHandle
    ' RELEASE RESOURCES
    Set xmldoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Err.Raise xslDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xslDoc.parseError.reason
    Resume ExitHandle    
End Sub
```

[image: Transformed XML Import]

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't seem to permit calling from a URL and formatting using a schema?

Comment: You can download XML content from a URL with MSXML and use XSLT as this answer shows to style for tabular format (one-level child of repeating elements).

Comment: Sorry Parfait I don't want to waste your time and I've been curious about XSLT so that was interesting, but it is not an option for me. My schema definition changes, so the formatting has to be based on the schema definition, and by formatting I mean formatted as a date, integer, string, etc. I don't see any URL in your answer and I tried OpenXML passing a URL instead of a filename and it didn't work, although the error was not clear.

Comment: Interestingly, I see no URL in your posted question! And you would pass a url with an MSXML object. In this example, xml and xsl is passed as local file but you could: `xmldoc.Load "http://www.example.com` and to save for OpenXML to import: `xmldoc.Save "C:\Path\to\File.xml"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point for dynamically determining column names. It prints some of the info about each node in *immediate window*. Further work would be needed to extract the names of the columns in a meaningful way:

```vb
Sub Create_XSD()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Count To 1 Step -1    'Delete all XML maps - to establish clean test environment
        ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(i).Delete
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear

    Dim strMyXml As String
    strMyXml = "<BookInfo>" _
             & "<Book>" _
             & "<ISBN>Text</ISBN>" _
             & "<Title>Text</Title>" _
             & "<Author>Text</Author>" _
             & "<Quantity>999</Quantity>" _
             & "</Book>" _
             & "<Book></Book>" _
             & "</BookInfo>"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False                      ' Turn off warning messages

    Dim myMap As XmlMap
    Set myMap = ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add(strMyXml)         ' this creates text that could be saved in an XSD file

    ' try this one
'   Set myMap = ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=90210")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Dim myXSD As String
    myXSD = ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps(1).Schemas(1).xml         ' XSD text

    Debug.Print vbCrLf & String(50, "*") & vbCrLf
    Debug.Print myXSD & vbCrLf & String(50, "-") & vbCrLf

'    MsgBox myXSD

' ---------------------------------------------------------------
'    Dim node As IXMLDOMNode
'    Dim nList As IXMLDOMNodeList
'    Dim nSel As IXMLDOMSelection

    Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument
    Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument
    xmlDoc.LoadXML myXSD

    printElement xmlDoc.ChildNodes, 1              ' prints stuff in immediate window (press ctrl-G to view)
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & String(50, "*") & vbCrLf

'    Set node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("xsd:schema")
'    Set nList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("xsd:schema")

'    Set node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("xsd:element")
'    Set nSel = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("xsd:element")
'    Set nList = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("xsd:schema").SelectNodes("xsd:element")

Stop   ' look at xml source in workbook

    myMap.Delete
    Set myMap = Nothing

End Sub
'

Sub printElement(L As IXMLDOMNodeList, lev As Integer)

    Dim cN As Object, i As Integer

    For Each cN In L
        Debug.Print vbCrLf & "level: " & lev;

        Debug.Print Tab(lev * 2 + 10); cN.tagName;           ' indent each level ( tab() measures from begining of line )
        If (cN.tagName = "xsd:element") Then
            For i = 1 To cN.Attributes.Length
                Debug.Print Tab(lev * 2 + 14); cN.Attributes(i - 1).Name & String(2, vbTab) & cN.Attributes(i - 1).Value
            Next i
        End If
        printElement cN.ChildNodes, lev + 1
    Next cN

End Sub
'
```

Comment: I was avoiding this route..thanks for getting me started on it!

Comment: Great tip I picked up from Parfait's edit - if you add `<!-- language: vba -->` above your code block it'll syntax highlight properly.

Answer (score 0):

This code maps to a table, but it does not do it automatically. It does show the correct column headers:

```vb
Sub minimalXML()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Count To 1 Step -1    'Delete all XML maps - to establish clean test environment
        ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(i).Delete
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear


    Dim lstContacts As ListObject
    Dim objNewCol As ListColumn
    Dim strXPath As String

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("b5:b5"), , xlYes).Name = "myTable"

    Dim myMap As XmlMap
'   Set myMap = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("Root_Map")
    Set myMap = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add("C:\Users\js\Desktop\excelWork\Expenses.xsd", "Root")

    Debug.Print myMap.RootElementName
'   Debug.Print myMap.Schemas(1).xml

    myMap.AdjustColumnWidth = True
'   myMap.AppendOnImport = False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False              ' hide warning about column width
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable").ListColumns(1).XPath.SetValue myMap, "/Root/EmployeeInfo/Name"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable").ListColumns.Add.XPath.SetValue myMap, "/Root/EmployeeInfo/Code"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable").ListColumns.Add.XPath.SetValue myMap, "/Root/ExpenseItem/Description"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable").ListColumns.Add.XPath.SetValue myMap, "/Root/ExpenseItem/Amount"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable").HeaderRowRange.ClearContents    ' show headers from xsd file

'    myMap.DataBinding.ClearSettings      ' not sure if this is needed

'    myMap.DataBinding.LoadSettings "C:\Users\js\Desktop\excelWork\Expenses.xsd"
'    myMap.DataBinding.Refresh

    myMap.Import "C:\Users\js\Desktop\excelWork\Expenses.xsd"  ' shorter version of two lines before this


    ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport "C:\Users\js\Desktop\excelWork\Expenses.xml", myMap, True

'    ActiveSheet.XmlMapQuery("/Root/EmployeeInfo/Name").Select       ' refer to column by name


'    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1).WorkbookConnection.Ranges(1).Formula(1, 1)
'    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1).WorkbookConnection.Ranges(1).ListObject.QueryTable.CommandText
'    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1).WorkbookConnection.Ranges(1).ListObject.ListColumns.Count
'    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1).WorkbookConnection.Ranges(1).Areas.Count
'    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1).WorkbookConnection.Ranges(1).Cells.Count
'    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1).WorkbookConnection.Ranges(1).CurrentRegion.Count
'    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1).WorkbookConnection.Ranges(1).Areas.Count

Stop

    ActiveSheet.Cells.Delete
    myMap.Delete

    Set myMap = Nothing

End Sub
'
```

Expenses.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Root>
  <EmployeeInfo>
    <Name>Jane Winston</Name>
    <Date>2001-01-01</Date>
    <Code>0001</Code>
  </EmployeeInfo>
  <ExpenseItem>
    <Date>2001-01-01</Date>
    <Description>Airfare</Description>
    <Amount>500.34</Amount>
  </ExpenseItem>
  <ExpenseItem>
    <Date>2001-01-01</Date>
    <Description>Hotel</Description>
    <Amount>200</Amount>
  </ExpenseItem>
</Root>
```

Expenses.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EmployeeInfo">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
              <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" />
              <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Date" />
              <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Code" />
            </xsd:all>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ExpenseItem">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:date"/>
              <xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="Amount" type="xsd:decimal" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Reference

- [Map XML elements to cells in an XML Map](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Map-XML-elements-to-cells-in-an-XML-Map-ddb23edf-f5c5-4fbf-b736-b3bf977a0c53?CorrelationId=7e05aef1-7285-4d36-b128-ed3632a72ab9&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HP010206397)

Answer (score 0):

1- open a new xlsx document

2- in developer tag - Source

3- Click On XML maps...

4- add

4.1 - browse for xsd

5- Click Ok

6- in drag subfolder to second row

6.1- fill data

7- in developer tag - Export

8- Choice XML

9- End process to MAP XSD

10- Save XLSX

SAVE A MACRO EXPORTING FROM DEVELOPER TAG

TRY IT !!!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I don't have XSD and the XML comes from an API, and when I recorded a macro it skipped the mapping. But maybe this'll be useful to someone coming here thanks.