# Map XML Elements to Columns in Excel with VBA

Tags: xml, vba

I've tried hundreds of websites by now and I still cannot map the elements of my XML to columns in Excel.

The closest solution seems to be the following:

https://flylib.com/books/en/2.485.1.129/1/

as well as this thread:

[Automatically map an Excel XmlMap to a worksheet in VBA without knowing the schema XPaths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046249/automatically-map-an-excel-xmlmap-to-a-worksheet-in-vba-without-knowing-the-sche)

So, I know how to load in the XML map to the XML source with VBA (that's an easy part):

e.g.

```
Sub Load()

ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add("C:\New Folder\sample_map.xml", "BATCH").Name = "BATCH_Map"

End Sub
```

Can you please advise? How to map e.g. `<FIRST_NAME>CAT</FIRST_NAME>` to `B1` ? If I know how to do it with one, the rest should follow nicely. Much obliged

The XML content:

```
- <BATCH xmlns="XXX">
- <HEADER>
  <COUNT>2</COUNT>
  <ORIGINATOR>XXYY</ORIGINATOR>
  </HEADER>
- <SUBMISSIONS>
- <SUBMISSION>
- <SUB_HEADER>
- <EVENTS>
- <EVENT>
  <CODE>RF01</CODE>
  <OPERATION>I</OPERATION>
  </EVENT>
  </EVENTS>
- <NOTES>
  <NOTE type="ACT" privacyLevel="PRIV">test</NOTE>
  </NOTES>
  </SUB_HEADER>
  <PRODUCT>NONSTANDARDREF</PRODUCT>
  <DATE>2020-01-01</DATE>
  <IDENTIFIER>X1</IDENTIFIER>
  <CLASSIFICATION>ACCEPT</CLASSIFICATION>
  <CATEGORY>AAA</CATEGORY>
- <PER_REF>
  <FIRST_NAME>CAT</FIRST_NAME>
  <SURNAME>DOG</SURNAME>
  <DOB>1800-01-01</DOB>
  <STATUS>OPEN</STATUS>
- <PER_REF_AD>
  <BUILDING_NAME>CASTLE</BUILDING_NAME>
  <STREET>TEST</STREET>
  <POST_TOWN>TEST</POST_TOWN>
  <COUNTY>TEST</COUNTY>
  <POSTCODE>AA1 1AA</POSTCODE>
  <STATUS>OPEN</STATUS>
  </PER_REF_AD>
  </PER_REF>
  </SUBMISSION>
- <SUBMISSION>
- <SUB_HEADER>
- <EVENTS>
- <EVENT>
  <CODE>A1</CODE>
  <OPERATION>I</OPERATION>
  </EVENT>
  </EVENTS>
- <NOTES>
  <NOTE type="XXX" privacyLevel="XXXX">test1</NOTE>
  </NOTES>
  </SUB_HEADER>
  <PRODUCT>Ec</PRODUCT>
  <DATE>2020-02-02</DATE>
  <IDENTIFIER>AB1</IDENTIFIER>
  <CLASSIFICATION>ACCEPT</CLASSIFICATION>
  <CATEGORY>AAA</CATEGORY>
- <PER_REF>
  <FIRST_NAME>ELEPHANT</FIRST_NAME>
  <SURNAME>HIPPO</SURNAME>
  <DOB>1900-02-02</DOB>
  <STATUS>OPEN</STATUS>
- <PER_REF_AD>
  <BUILDING_NAME>1</BUILDING_NAME>
  <STREET>TEST</STREET>
  <POST_TOWN>TEST</POST_TOWN>
  <COUNTY>TEST</COUNTY>
  <POSTCODE>BB1 1BB</POSTCODE>
  <STATUS>OPEN</STATUS>
  </PER_REF_AD>
  </PER_REF>
  </SUBMISSION>
  </SUBMISSIONS>
  </BATCH>
```

Comment: There are a bunch of different approaches outlined in the SO question you linked to: none of those meet your needs?  It's unclear why none of them can work for your specific case.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have managed to successfully reverse engineer the example from the first link. I will implement it in my case now (hopefully it will work) and then post an answer for others. :)